# OneNote API - Subscribe to PageUpdates

Tags: c#, onenote, onenote-api

I Understand that the OneNote API is a Rest API, but is there any way to subscribe to page changes (other than re querying the page and checking for changes manually).

If not is there any plans to create such mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have something currently. But this is a common ask (as seen on [UserVoice](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-apis/suggestions/5657698-support-for-webhooks-so-i-can-get-notification-whe)). So yes, we have started looking into it.